# Selecting a VB6 DLL reference in one Access file somehow selects it in another

Tags: ms-access, dll, vb6

**The Setup**

I have a VB6 dll that works with an Access 2013 application.
There are two versions: `dev.dll` and `prod.dll`.
Both share the same code, but differ only by name (which should make them distinct COM objects).

To deploy, I:

- Make `prod.dll`
- Copy the development .accdb file to the production version
- In production, change the `dev.dll` reference to `prod.dll`

**The Problem**

After doing this, I happened to recheck the dll reference in the development version. It was `prod.dll` -- not `dev.dll` as I was expecting!

Curious, I opened both the development and production .accdb files side-by-side.
Sure enough, when I changed the reference for one file, some invisible hand changed the reference in the other.

This behavior persisted when I opened one file by itself and changed its reference. After closing it and reopened the other, the reference had auto-magically changed.

Everything compiles OK. There are no orphan MSACCESS.exe instances floating around in Task Manager.

**Questions**

- Has anyone else observed this behavior?
- Should I worry about this?
- Is there a fix?

Comment: If the only difference between the two dlls is truly the filename, that is not sufficient to distinguish them.  It sounds like they both have the same COM interface definitions, so what you describe would be the expected behavior.  Are these separate projects (that is, you have two vbp files)? If so, check the Version Compatibility settings on the Component tab of Project-Properties for each project, I'd expect that they both point t the same compatibility target, which means they both expose the same COM interface.

Comment: @MarkL - The `Name` attribute in the `dev.vbp` and `prod.vbp`  files are set to 'dev' and 'prod', respectively. This has always been enough for the COM system to tell them apart in the past.

Comment: @MarkL - The other thing to note is the `prod` project is a snapshot in time of `dev`. The `dev` compatibility target is copied to `prod` as part of this process. So, they share the same COM interface until breaking changes get made in the `dev` project. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 3):

Well some reference to some other Access database is NOT being added or changed out of the blue here.

You ALREADY have a reference to that registered .dll in BOTH applications. If you re-reigsiter the .dll, and regiser under the same name, then both applcations will still go look for that regisered dll by the name you gave it and thus both will change.

I mean, fire up a access database WITHOUT a reference to the regisered .dll, and THEN see what happens?
Answer: nothing at all!!!!

So, access does on startup try to load nd find the regisered .dll. In fact, you see this if you have say a reference to Excel 14. Now run the same applcation on a computer with Excel 15 or 16 - guess, what, the reference changes!!!!

so you have not shared your regsvr32 command you are using, but they have both a .dll, and the name that will appear when you use VBA->tools->references and set a reference to that .dll. If you THEN re-register the .dll, but the text for the reference in VBA stays the same, then access will flip and use the new registered .dll. Unless you give a 100% different name for the text part, then re-registering the .dll means that access on startup is able to see and find the text part name used, and thus will flip and now point to the new .dll.

And bonus question:
Do and can and do you have BOTH .dlls regiserted at the same time and on the same computer? Since if you do, then they will have not only a different path to the .dll, but ALSO a different name and text that displays, right?

So, if both .dlls are regisered on the computer at the same time, then they have different names, and thus this flip will not occur then, will it?

But, you not AT ANY POINT in time demonstrating that some accDB file by magic get, or has or sees some new reference set out of the blue. Your testing and example has the databases WITH AN ALREADY reference set, and you now re-registering the .dll used, but with the same name!!! it is for this reason the flip is occurring here, since the path name to the .dll changes, but not the text reference you see/use/pick when setting up the reference in the first place.

In fact, I would suggest you test this with both .dll's registered, and then set a reference in Access  to both .dlls at the same time. Doing so will make what is occurring here very clear!

Now, it is possible that the above is not your case and scenario, and somthing else may well be going on here. But, I would test this with BOTH .dlls registered, and in VBA references settings, now have a reference to both .dlls. Do that, and you get your answer as to what is going on here.

Comment: Albert: thanks for your insights. It turns out that the `dev.dll` and `prod.dll` both share the same GUID, which surprised me since the projects have different names. I wound up remaking both DLLs with slight changes to their public interface. While the GUIDs never changed, the weird "selecting for one changed it for the other" behavior is gone. I'm not sure if I made some subtle mistake in preparing the earlier DLLs, or it was just a fluke, but the problem resolved itself. Anyway, I appreciate you looking into it.

Comment: Always kind when someone comes back - even when the result is not fantastic. My suggesting that the same name was being picked up - might be perhaps guid is being used behind. But, access does on startup "can" muck around with the references a wee bit, and if same name, but path name change - it does and can flip (and does so for word, outlook etc.). However, with different name(s), then of course no problem. All good, and good luck!